# Expression Engine Plugin for Changes Log

Tags: plugin, developer-log

Is there a way or a plugin that keeps a log of who changed what for pages and templates [and other things if possible]?

Answer (score 2):

I found that Audit Pro does the job! Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple options available for tracking changes in content:

[Better Workflow](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/better-workflow) and [Publisher](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/publisher)

These do not work for templates, though. I would suggest using Git to track template changes.